# Why is an empty H2 database 2 MB in size?

Tags: database, h2

I'm building an application that uses an embedded H2 database. I used the tutorial to test it out and everything seemed to work fine:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] a)
            throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.
            getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
        // add application code here
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

I am curious however, in my home directory I now have a "test.h2" file along with a "test.lock" file. Why does an empty database end up being 2 MB? It seems kind of large, I would expect something in KB at most, given that all that is in it would be some default empty memory and some instructions for storing data in it. Is 2 MB the default memory allocated?

Comment: Never noticed.  I know it creates a bunch of tables in its INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  One thing I just noticed is a HELP table, which contains 321 rows of help text for various commands.  Maybe the help text is just enough to get it to this size?

Comment: Couldn't see any obvious answer in the docs.

Comment: Are you connected to the database? If so disconnect and then see the size of it. I notice that if I do this then the size shrinks to 24Kb

Comment: Also what version of H2 are you using?

Comment: @JavaDevil the latest version, I downloaded it a week ago. I've disconnected and it is still 2 MB. (I'm on Windows 64 bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database file size of an empty (or almost empty) database is only 2 MB while the database is open. If it is closed, the file shrinks.

On some file systems, resizing files is relatively slow. Because of that, H2 allocates more space than it needs: to reduce the number of resize operations.

The exact algorithm to expand the file size may change in the future. Currently, the minimum file size is about 2 MB. The file grows at 35%, but at most 256 MB at a time.

When you close the database, the file shrinks to the real size needed.

Comment: Can't get a more authoritative answer than that :)